# Why is the first element in my d3 data not being updated?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I am currently using this code to render a list of elements and (hopefully) designate the active element, which can change when one of the elements is clicked.

```js
let active_experiment_id = null;

function set_experiments() {
    const u = d3.select('#experiments')
          .selectAll('li')
          .data(Object.values(experiments).sort((a, b) => {
              const a_time = moment(a['created']),
                    b_time = moment(b['created']);
              if (a_time.isBefore(b_time))
                  return 1;
              else if (a_time.isAfter(b_time))
                  return -1;
              else
                  return 0;
          }), (d) => d);

    const entering = u.enter()
          .append('li')
          .classed('nav-item', true)
          .classed('active', (d) => d.active_experiment)
          .on('click', d => {
              if (d.experiment_id !== active_experiment_id)
                  set_active_experiment(d.experiment_id);
          })
          .append('a')
          .classed('nav-link', true)
          .classed('active', (d) => d.active_experiment)
          .append('p')
          .text((d) => { return d.name; });

    u.exit().remove();
}

function set_active_experiment(experiment_id) {
    if (experiment_id === null) {
        active_experiment_id = null;
        set_classes(null);
        set_workflows(null);
        set_tasks(null);
        set_seleced_task(null, null);
        return;
    }
    if (active_experiment_id !== null)
        experiments[active_experiment_id].active_experiment = false;
    active_experiment_id = experiment_id;
    experiments[active_experiment_id].active_experiment = true;

    fetch_tasks(experiment_id)
        .then(() => {
            set_experiments();
            set_classes(experiment_id);
            set_workflows(experiment_id);
            set_tasks(experiment_id);
            set_selected_task(experiment_id, experiments[experiment_id].root_task_id);
        });
}
```

I currently have two data elements in the list and I'm able to click the second and get the `active` class to be applied. However, I can't get the first to be clicked. I tried debugging, but the enter function wasn't even called on he first task (experiment_id = 2 below). The elements look like:

```
experiments = {1: {
  experiment_id: 1,
  name: "Experiment One",
  created: (before 2)
  ...
}, 2: {
  experiment_id: 2,
  name: "Experiment Two",
  created: (after 1),
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem and more of a matter of style and taste: your entire data binding can be significantly simplified to `.data(Object.values(experiments).sort((a, b) => moment(b.created).diff(moment(a.created))), d => d)`. `moment.fn.diff()` will evaluate to the sign you are interested in for the comparator function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out the issue. Because I used `Object.values`, somehow only the second experiment held it's position. After that, since data was bound directly by reference (using key `(d) => d`), d3 would compare an element to itself as the key test. So, no matter what key method you choose, d3 would still compare on object's key against itself and not register that the object had updated. So, to fix this, I create a projected copy of the data every time and use a new key method to reduce the number of objects going through `enter` and `exit`.

```js
function set_experiments() {
    const key = d => `${d.experiment_id}${d.active_experiment}`;

    const data = Object.values(experiments).sort((a, b) => {
        const a_time = moment(a['created']),
              b_time = moment(b['created']);
        if (a_time.isBefore(b_time))
            return 1;
        else if (a_time.isAfter(b_time))
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    })
          .map(d => ({
              "experiment_id": d.experiment_id,
              "created": d.created,
              "name": d.name,
              "active_experiment": d.active_experiment,
          }));

    const u = d3.select('#experiments')
          .selectAll('li')
          .data(data, key);

    const entering = u.enter()
          .append('li')
          .classed('nav-item', true)
          .classed('active', (d) => {
              num_entered++;
              return d.active_experiment;
          })
          .on('click', d => {
              if (d.experiment_id !== active_experiment_id) {
                  set_active_experiment(d.experiment_id);
              }
          })
          .append('a')
          .classed('nav-link', true)
          .classed('active', (d) => {
              return d.active_experiment;
          })
          .append('p')
          .text((d) => { return d.name; });

    u.exit().remove();
}
```

While it isn't the most efficient, as I still have to copy all of the data, the copied data isn't affecting the DOM. Only the updated values are, since the new key method removes redundant additions and removals.